# Javascript Form Validation issue how to reveal condition input field

Tags: javascript, validation

I'm using Bootstrap and Vanilla Javascript. It is a very simple form, really.

My problem, as I have not done any Javascript in a few years, is how to get around the first thing I need help about.

Now to the problem:

```
IF the user select "Near_death" in the drop down. a new form must be shown. This has been hidden as long as no one chooses "Near_Death". Such as.

<div class="form-group">
   <select id="types" name="types" class="form-control">
   <option value="Near_death">Near_death</option>
   <option value="1" type="number">1</option>
   <option value="2" type="number">2</option>
   <option value="3" type="number">3</option>
     </select>
 </div>
```

I expect the lower form to revel itself if the user check the "Near_death" form option. It's just a case of conditional hide/show but I cannot for the life if me remember how I used to do it.

Please, Only Vanilla JavaScript. Thank you all for any help. Much appreciated! :=)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your html**

```
<div class="form-group">
   <select id="types" name="types" class="form-control">
   <option value="Near_death">Near_death</option>
   <option value="1" type="number">1</option>
   <option value="2" type="number">2</option>
   <option value="3" type="number">3</option>
     </select>
 </div>

<div id="form_for_near_death">
  form_for_near_death 
</div>
```

**Required CSS**

```
#form_for_near_death{
  display:none;
}
```

**Required JS**

Bind an `event` to the `select box` and toggle the form display based on your selection. This is done using below script

```
<script>
var selectbox = document.getElementById("types");

selectbox.addEventListener("change",function(event){
  toggleForm(event);
})

var toggleForm = function(event){
  var selectedValue = (typeof event === "string") ? event : event.target.value;
  var formObject = document.getElementById("form_for_near_death");
  if(selectedValue === "Near_death"){
    formObject.style.display="block";
    return;
  }
  formObject.style.display="none";
}
toggleForm(selectbox.value);
</script>
```

You can check the output for this code in [my codepen](https://codepen.io/Divine1/pen/yrYJej)

Comment: A heartfelt thanks for your time! Helps a lot! :D

Answer (score 1):

You would do this by running the following code in an on change event of the select. Example below:

```
var myForm = document.getElementById("myForm"); //your form id

var types = document.getElementById("types");
var selectedItem = types.options[types.selectedIndex].text;

if(selectedItem == "Near_death"){
   myForm.style.display = "block";
}
else{
   myForm.style.display = "none";
}
```

Note: sorry this isn't tested but hopefully sends you on the right track :)

Comment: Thank you very much Money Murch! :)